# Can I override my application's build-in App Store Icon via iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I need to update the App Store icon in my app.

In iTunes Connect, under General App Information, there is a place where you can upload an App Store icon. The help link next to it shows the following:

> "This icon will be used on the App Store. For apps built with Xcode 9 or later, add this icon in the build. For apps built with earlier versions of Xcode, add the icon here."

My app *was* built with Xcode 9 or later, and it does have an icon built-in via the build, but I'd rather not build/package/sign/upload my entire app just to update this icon. **If I upload an App Store icon via iTunes Connect, will it take precedent over the one built-in to my binary?**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: yes, the App Store icon uploaded via iTunes Connect overrides the one built into your binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a new large icon to iTunes Connect, but it will not appear in the customer's iOS App Store app or web page until an update to the app is approved by Apple.

The icon uploaded to iTunes Connect (separate from the build upload) only affects the icon as it appears in the App Store, not the icon that appears on the customer's iOS device springboard.